# Bootstrap tab pane will not toggle when using href hash route

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, tabs

Would like to use a basic hash router to drive navigation of bootstrap 4.6 tab component.

However when I call the .tab('show') function, the right tab toggles but it's respective tab-pane section does not get toggled. I made sure the tab-panes id attribute has the same value as the tabs href attribute.

I was able to make it work by manually showing and hiding the tab panes. But bootstrap has this functionality built in. Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thanks

```js
hashRouteInit = function(callback) {
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', callback, false);
}

const routes = {
  '#/units': function() {
    console.log('units');
  },
  '#/clients': function() {
    console.log('clients');
  },
  '#/searches': function() {
    console.log('searches');
  },

};

hashRouteInit(function() {
  console.log(window.location.hash);
  console.log(routes);
  if (routes[window.location.hash] != undefined) {

    /*how can i remove the following 3 lines and let .tab('show') show the tab pane*/
    /*$(`.tab-content .show`).hide();
    $(`.tab-content .show`).removeClass('show');
    $(`.tab-content .show`).removeClass('active');*/

    $(`#stats-tabs a[href="${window.location.hash}"]`).tab('show');

    /*how can i remove the following 3 lines and let .tab('show') show the tab pane*/
    /*$(`.tab-content .tab-pane[id="${window.location.hash}"]`).addClass('show');
    $(`.tab-content .tab-pane[id="${window.location.hash}"]`).addClass('active');
    $(`.tab-content .tab-pane[id="${window.location.hash}"]`).show();*/

    routes[window.location.hash]();

  }
});
```

```html
<head>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="stats-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" id="units-tab" href="#/units" role="tab" aria-controls="units" aria-selected="true">Units</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" id="clients-tab" href="#/clients" role="tab" aria-controls="clients" aria-selected="false">Clients</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" id="searches-tab" href="#/searches" role="tab" aria-controls="searches" aria-selected="false">Searches</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content pt-2" id="stats-tabs-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="#/units" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="units-tab">units</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="#/clients" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="clients-tab">clients</div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="#/searches" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="searches-tab">
        <div id="search-overview-searches">searches</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the HTML ID attribute has to start with a letter(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Once I set the href attributes to #name and used the same value but without the number sign for the ID of the tab pane. It started working.

Note that the spec([https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#:~:text=The%20id%20attribute%20specifies%20its,not%20contain%20any%20space%20characters.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#:%7E:text=The%20id%20attribute%20specifies%20its,not%20contain%20any%20space%20characters.)) doesn't say anything about not using slashes to construct a hierarchy in the id string. However if i want to have another tab section as a child in a tab pane, i won't be able to have an id like this(parent/child) and have bootstrap tabs work. So you are only left with - or _ which doesn't seem so intuitive in the URI. Especially once you wan't to add an numerical identifier onto it. Like so parent/child/3. Can't do that, but the spec doesn't say anything about not allowing slashes.

Does anyone know why forward slashes are not allowed in the id string if the first char is not a forward slash?